# excel: compare 3 column's numbers, decide on the largest number and place the column header in the 4th column

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

i want to compare the numbers of three columns, row by row, decide on the largest number and then place the title of the column of the largest number in a fourth column. the fourth column will end up having column headers of largest values.

Columns to be compared are A5:110(APPLES), B5:C110(ORANGES), C5:C110(GRAPES)

When a value/number, for example A12 is greater than B12 & C12 i would like 'APPLES' placed in the fourth column' D' within the equaliviant row which is D12 in this example.

I appreciate your comein in this! thanks in advance

madsnow

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better way to do this, but see below.  The formula in cell D5 is

=CHOOSE(MATCH(LARGE(A5:C5,1),A5:C5,0),$A$4,$B$4,$C$4)

Just copy the formula all the way down in column D.

[image]